# Android rhombus drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I have a question - how to draw scalable rhombus drawable in android xml's?
I want to draw something like this: [image: rhombus]

I tried to draw rectangle and rotate it 45 degrees:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:bottom="10dp">
   <rotate
       android:fromDegrees="45"
       android:toDegrees="45"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%" >
      <shape
          android:shape="rectangle" >
         <solid
             android:color="@color/accent" />
      </shape>
   </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

But result is awful, one corner is higher than other:
[image: rhombus 2]
I think it is because cell is not square. So, how to draw rhombus which could be scaled without problems?

Comment: How is the text rendered? I'm guessing that the width of the two digits is skewing the shape.

Comment: Text is centered in text view and this drawable is set as background to it.

Comment: inside your shape tag, give size tag too and give same values for both height and width. dont worry about the value, make it 5dp for each. giving same value will ensure the aspect ratio for the drawable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but thanks to your drawable I could find the way to draw a rhombus, your issue was the height and width, in my case I want to put it on a view of 12dp so my width is half of that if some one has to do this again this is the answer your result will be something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:height="6dp" android:width="6dp" android:right="2dp"
      android:left="2dp">
   <rotate
                   android:fromDegrees="45"
                   android:pivotX="50%"
                   android:pivotY="50%" >
      <shape
                      android:shape="rectangle" >
         <solid
                         android:color="@color/genioAccent" />
      </shape>
   </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Don't height and width attributes in drawables only work since API 23?

Comment: Yes, you are right but they never say what version they are using @EugenPechanec

Comment: hahaa but actually for not 23 sdk there is no issue with top,bottom, the issue he is facing is just for sdk 23

Answer (score 0):

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:right="50dp"
            android:left="50dp"
            android:top="50dp"
            android:bottom="50dp">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:pivotX="50%">
    
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <solid android:color="@color/green_700"/>
                    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
                </shape>
    
            </rotate>
    
        </item>
    
    </layer-list>
```